# MVC multiple views for a single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible in MVC to do the following with a single controller "ListController" to take care of the following pages...

> www.example.com/List/Cars/ForSale/{id} optional
>
> www.example.com/List/Cars/ForRent/{id} optional
>
> www.example.com/List/Search/
>
> www.example.com/List/Boats/ForSale/{id} optional
>
> www.example.com/List/Boats/ForRent/{id} optional
>
> www.example.com/List/Boats/Search/

If not, is there any way to get around it besides making a CarsController and BoatsController separate? They will be using the same logic just would like the URLs different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can definitely do this.  It is simple using routing. You can route the different urls to different actions in your controller.

Here are examples of defining some of the above urls:

```
routes.MapRoute("CarSale"
    "/List/Cars/ForSale/{id}",
    new { controller = "list", action = "carsale", id =  UrlParameter.Optional } );

routes.MapRoute("ListSearch"
    "/List/search",
    new { controller = "list", action = "search"} );


routes.MapRoute("BoatSale"
    "/List/Boats/ForSale/{id}",
    new { controller = "list", action = "boatsale", id =  UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Then in your controller you would have action methods for each:

```
public ListController 
{
    // ... other stuff 

    public ActionResult CarSale(int? id)
    {
      // do stuff

      return View("CarView");
    }

    public ActionResult BoatSale(int? id)
    {
      // do stuff

      return View("BoatView");
    }

        // ... other stuff 
}
```

Comment: Or you could make the type of item a parameter too, al a `routes.MapRoute("Sale", "/List/{itemtype}/ForSale{id}", /*...*/)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Inside my controller how will I create the action result functions to tell the difference between Cars/ForSale/{id}, Cars/ForSale/ and Boats/ForSale/{id}, Boats/ForSale/

Comment: I update the code to show actions which will render different views.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes You can use multiple **View** in one Controller.

Let's take one Example,
I have one **Controller** Called **Lawyers**

```
public class LawyersController : Controller
{
    // GET: Lawyers
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    } 
    public ActionResult Signup()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

so I have one controller and 2 views.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 6 years ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a dramatically better alternative approach to the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Routes could also be specified above methods with decorators so no need for RouteConfig. You just need to omit the "controller/" part from the route.

```
public ListController 
{
    // ... other stuff 
    [Route("Cars/ForSale/{id}")]
    public ActionResult CarSale(int? id)
    {
      // do stuff

      return View("CarView");
    }

    [Route("Boats/ForSale/{id}")]
    public ActionResult BoatSale(int? id)
    {
      // do stuff

      return View("BoatView");
    }

        // ... other stuff 
}
```